# My function seems to be correct but i get compiling error

Tags: c++, function, compilation

For some odd reason, when I try to compile I get the error code LNK2019 with this description:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__PathCombineW@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl createEnvironment(wchar_t *,struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *,struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *)" (?createEnvironment@@YAXPA_WPAU_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES@@1@Z)  Umberella
>   F:\Projects\Umberella\Umberella\main.obj    1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

using namespace std;


void createEnvironment (wchar_t* lpPathName, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributesRest)
{

    //Create the main directory
    CreateDirectory(lpPathName, lpSecurityAttributes);

    //Combine main with subfolder and put it in buffer loggdir
wchar_t* tempERRLoggDir = L"//Reportlogg";
wchar_t loggERRdir[MAX_PATH];
PathCombine(loggERRdir, lpPathName, tempERRLoggDir);

CreateDirectory(loggERRdir, lpSecurityAttributesRest);

    return;
}

void main (void)
{
    //Define main directory
    wchar_t* mainDir = L"C://Umberella";
    createEnvironment(mainDir, NULL, NULL);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a compiler error, it is a linker error.  You are missing the library where `PathCombine` is defined.

Add this after your `#include` headers:

`#pragma comment (lib, "shlwapi")`

This will link in the `shlwapi.lib` file required to satisfy the linker.